# Calculating $ \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \int_{0}^{t} (\arctan{x})^2\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

How do you go about calculating this integral? $$ \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \int_{0}^{t} (\arctan{x})^2\,dx$$

I know that $$ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t} \int_{0}^{t} f(x)dx = f(0)$$ and I think these two are connected, but I cannot quite figure it out what should I start with. Hints appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to l'Hospital's Rule
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\int_{0}^{t}(\arctan x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x= \lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{\arctan^2(x)}{\frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}.
\end{equation*}

Comment: I feel like a dumbass,, it was really not that hard. Using l'Hospital's Rule we can prove the second equaility too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\lim_{t\to\infty}\arctan(t)$ is a non-zero constant. Then so is $\lim_{t\to\infty}\arctan^2(t)$. The integral of a constant is ...

Comment: Beat me to it. Nice work (+1)

Comment: I am sorry but i do not understand :( why are we taking limit of arctan?

Comment: I don't think it works.

Comment: $\arctan(100)$ is about $89.4^\circ$. In radians, that's pretty close to $\frac{\pi}2$. So for large $x$ values, $\arctan(x)\approx\frac{\pi}2$, and $\int_0^t\arctan^2(x)dx\approx\frac{\pi^2}4\int_0^tdx=\frac{\pi^2}4t$. The more you integrate (larger $t$), the better the approximation.

Comment: Okay, so the idea is that for large $t$ we can treat $\arctan^2(x)$ as a constant and *intuitively* i could see why that works. Yet I feel like this is kind of informal thinking and i have got no idea how to formalize it. Do You think there is a way to use the second property mentioned in the post?

Comment: I don't see how you can use the second property, since you are going in the wrong direction with the limit. There you make the integration range as small as possible, here you try to make it go to infinity. With the condition that $f$ is finite, this is $\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t\int_0^tf(x)dx=f(\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Use the substitution $x = ty$

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\int_0^t\arctan^2(x)\:dx = \lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\int_0^1\arctan^2(ty)\:dy$$